# Зачем используется await/async при обращениях к базе?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Не могу понять.
В старых примерах кода обычно писалость что-то вроде такого.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id) 
{
    var item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
    return View(item);
}
```

а в новых примерах уже идёт везде ассинхронный вариант

```
public async  Task<ActionResult> Index(int id) 
{
    var item = await db.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == id);
    return View(item);
}
```

не могу понять в чём разница, и почему сейчас используется второй вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы корректно ответить на твой вопрос надо понимать что такое async/await "под капотом". В двух словах — это новая концепция работы с наименьшей на текущий момент затратой системных ресурсов. Конкретнее в твоем примере:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id) 
{
    var item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
    return View(item);
}
```

синхронный возов внутри текущего потока. Это означает, что поток будет занят, пока ответ не придет от БД. Если это UI поток, то у тебя приложение "будет висеть" ожидая ответа. Затраты системных ресурсов — блокировка потока до окончания операции.

```
public async  Task<ActionResult> Index(int id) 
{
    var item = await db.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == id);
    return View(item);
}
```

Что происходит тут? создается неявно таск, который асинхронно отправляет задачу извлечения данных и поток вызова не блокируется, идет дальше на выход и выше. Кроме тот, поток таска тоже не ждет! Он отправляет задачу на выполнение и отдает свой поток обратно в ThreadPool, а потом, как ответ придет, любой поток (иногда не любой) из ThreadPool-а получит ответ, обработает его и исполнит кусок кода, который идет после вызова await.